# Discrepancy between two integration methods

Tags: calculus, integration

I intergated $(2x-6)^2$ by expanding the bracket first and got $\frac43x^3-12x^2+36x+c$. I then tried a different method and used the reverse chain rule for integration and got $\frac16(2x-6)^3$. The two answers are clearly different. What am I misunderstanding here/doing wrong? I would be very grateful if somebody could explain this to me.

Comment: Try expanding your second expression. They're less different than you think!

Comment: Did you expand your second answer? What's the difference between them? When are two indefinite integrals considered the "same"?

Comment: I did! Following the expansion, the second answer is (4/3)(x^3)−12x^2+36x-36+c. So the difference is this term -36 which does not appear if the first method is used.

Comment: What do you think the "$+c$" means in the first expression?

Comment: Gotcha! I have one more question! If the above expression to intergrate is used as a part of definite integral, is the use of the first method preferred over the second? I got two different answers when using the two integration methods.

Comment: Just to give a bit of context, I had a definite integral specified between b and 3 and the value was equal to 36. For the first integration method b was 4.5, for the second 6.

Comment: When you have an antiderivative, you evaluate the definite integral by evaluating the antiderivative at the end points and taking the difference. But that means your expressions will be of the form $f(b)+C - f(a)-C=f(b)-f(a)$, i.e., the constant of integration cancels. So I'd recheck the values of the two antiderivatives at both endpoints.

Comment: I'm a fool! I mistyped a digit in my calculation! It all makes sense now. I appreciate all the input!